# PHP opening tags and XML declaration

Tags: php, xml, phpstorm

I am new in **PhpStorm** and I run into a problem when declaring xml on .php file, The problem I am talking about is that PhpStorm is refers the `<? ?>` as the short opening tags as php opening tags while I set **short_open_tag = Off** at the **php.ini**.

How can I set PhpStorm so it **won't** refer the short php opening tags as php opening tags?

Comment: Please provide some small code example to be sure on what you are talking about (screenshot of the actual error will also be useful).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your XML in a variable and output it:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
  <T3locallang>
    <meta type="array">
        <description>CSH for Content Elements Table.</description>
        <type>CSH</type>
        <csh_table>tt_content</csh_table>
    </meta>
  </T3locallang>
XML;

echo $xml;
?>
```

There is no other solution for PhpStorm, AFAIK.

Answer (score 7):

PHPStorm as of now does not have any setting for that (see [WI-2059 add "Disable short tags" option to project's options](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2059)).

So you can not set that so far. All you can do is to write the code in a way that it does not clash, for example by echoing the XML declaration processing instruction:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>' ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Variables, echos. Meh. Why not simply...

```
<<?php ?>?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

No mess, no complains from PHPStorm or whatever. Basically, you may even use just `<??>` instead of `<?php ?>`, if you don't need the absolutely bulletproof solution covering both `on` and `off` cases for `short_open_tag`.