# Windows php error on first line with <?

Tags: php, windows, lamp

I have a php script which starts with the following line

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

It works fine in the LAMP world but when I port it to Windows I think it thinks this line is code when it's not as I get this error in Visual Studio:

> Syntax error: unexpected token 'version'

Is there a way that I can get Windows php to not consider this to be code? I thought all code blocks had to start with `<?php`?

Comment: check the `php.ini` setting [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) and make sure that it's set to false

Comment: `<?php xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` What does this give you?

Comment: *"I thought all code blocks had to start with "<\?php"?"* as per original post http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32694982/1 - Err.. no. `<?php` yes, if you're actually using `<\?php` - Why was  `<\?php` edited to read as `<?php`? How do we know if that isn't what the OP isn't really using? as per this edit http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32694982/2 - question code should **NOT** be modified when doing an edit.

Comment: I performed a rollback on the question Rob. If you are indeed using `<?php` rather than `<\?php`, then by all means, edit your question accordingly. To: people doing editing (now and in the future); even though the OP might not be using `<\?php`, either way, when doing edits in a question, editing "code" in order to reflect what should be proper syntax, should NOT be performed. We're not here to play Code Gods.

Comment: It's an obvious typo of course I am using <?php it's difficult to enter with having to escape the characters right. It needs editing back.

Comment: ok it's just been a big distraction from the actual issue which Mark's comment has identified the solution to I think

Comment: @RobSedgwick Another thing is, if you might be using a class, it's usually best to leave out the closing `?>` tags in PHP. Just an insight.

Comment: Why is nobody asking why your supposedly PHP file begins with an XML preamble? Even if short tags are going to be enabled, `<?xml version="1.0"` will be interpreted as `<?php xml version="1.0"`, which won't work either.

Comment: The point is it's not code if short tags are disabled then it won't be considered as code but as plain text which it is.

Comment: Yeah alright let me rephrase that, why do you let PHP handle XML files? Does it have a `.php` extension, and if so, why? But yeah, disabling the short_open_tag will do, though that may break existing code (libraries0 that rely on it.

Comment: The PHP script is producing an XML file with dynamic content. It has to start with that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the header function of PHP to render this tag for you. Put this at the very first line of your code:

```
<? header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8") ?>
```

Then you won't have problems with the opening PHP tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can just output the XML declaration from PHP:

```
<?php
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n";

// ...
```

This will have the exact same output, and there is no confusion for the interpreter that this is in fact a PHP file.

This has another not-so-obvious advantage. Programs that use the few first bytes to analyze file contents instead of using the file extension will think that a file beginning with `<?xml` is a XML file, and can therefore report invalid content-type.
For example, the `file` command, for your example, prints:

```
foo.php: XML document text
```

while with my solution:

```
foo.php: PHP script, ASCII text
```

Also see [PHP opening tags and XML declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265905/php-opening-tags-and-xml-declaration), where the OP reported a similar issue causing PHPStorm to be confused by the first `<?` characters thinking it is PHP code.