# PHP throwing error on XML opening tag

Tags: php, php-parse-error

I have a file that is including a file named `sitemap.html` and in the sitemap, I have the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <url>
        <loc><?php echo SITE_URL . '/'; ?></loc>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>1.00</priority>
    </url>

    <?php foreach ($this->data->content as $content): ?>
        <url>
            <loc><?php echo SITE_URL . $content->permalink; ?></loc>
            <lastmod><?php echo date("Y-m-d", $content->publish_date); ?></lastmod>
            <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
            <priority><?php echo $content->sitemap_index; ?></priority>
        </url>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</urlset>
```

Everything seems okay, but I'm getting an error 500 that's saying:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'version' (T_STRING) in sitemap.html on line 1

As you can see, I'm using `<?xml` and not `<?php` so why is it trying to parse it as PHP?

At first, I thought it was the magic quotes that are causing an issue, but when I do a var_dump of [get_magic_quotes_gpc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php), I get `bool(false)` so the magic quotes aren't even on.

Also, in my `php.ini`, I see that `magic_quotes` is `OFF`.

As an alternative to fix it, I replaced my first line with the following:

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>
```

But I'm still curious about what's happening.

I have other websites hosted on the same server (PHP version 5.4.45), and I don't get the PHP Parse Error on the sitemap of the other websites...

Any idea what might be causing this error?

Comment: this is not magic quotes. it's short_open_tags, which makes php trigger on `<?` as well as `<?php`. magic quotes was the (moronically stupid) "automatically escape everything for sql usage" business.

Comment: @MarcB Oh I got mixed up.. My bad! However, I don't think that is the problem, because as I mentioned, I have other websites running the exact same code, and it's working for the other websites...

Comment: doesn't mean much. php settings can be overridden at the webserver level on a per-site basis. check the short_open_tag setting on the working/non-working sites.

Comment: @MarcB I looked everywhere in the project, and I can't seem to find anything related to `short_open_tag` in both the working and non-working projects.

Comment: The only `ini_set` that were found are related to `memory_limit`.

Comment: it can be anywhere, including webserver .conf/.htaccess, e.g. `php_value short_open_tag 0` or whatever. check `phpinfo()` on BOTH servers and see what the setting is on each.

Comment: @MarcB All the projects are on the same server. The `phpinfo()` shows that `short_open_tag` is active, yet the `<?xml` is working on all other projects.  I've also looked in the `.conf` and `.htaccess` and there seems to be nothing related to `short_open_tag`.

Comment: On the OTHER servers, are you parsing .html as .php? It fits that short_open_tag is on (you've confirmed; always turn it off for good practice ;) ) and on sites where it does not work as expected, those servers are set to process .html as .php (whereas the servers that work as expected, .html files are not pre-processed, but are served as HTML (which is normal, and also should be considered good practice).

Comment: @Robbie There's no OTHER server. All the projects, the one not working and the others that are working are on the same server. And yes, it's both .html parsed as .php

Comment: Sorry missed that bit. Check all the .htaccess for `AddHandler` or `AddType` declarations as it's possible to change behaviour individually for each directory/virtual server as it is for a physical server. You can also specify handlers per directory in .conf(s) so check all your configs as well. You'll have something like `AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .php .html` (or could be `AddHandler`) so check where it could be missing and/or overridden.

Comment: @Robbie No worries! I've already checked the .htaccess and the conf files. The .htaccess is the same as it's a custom CMS, and the conf file only differs in the directory path. Also, the php is rendering on all the .html files as well.

Comment: The reason for the error is, *without doubt*, the `short_open_tag` is enabled on one site and not on the other. It's impossible for anyone to give you a definitive reason how and why this is happening without seeing the full details the system. `short_open_tag` can be configured per virtual host, perhaps a library or framework, the sites could be running different versions of PHP, the list goes on. It's pretty much a guessing game without knowing the system. Stop thinking it's something else and tackle the issue from there. Use `var_dump(ini_get('short_open_tag'));exit;` to inspect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should check `short_open_tag` option. The way i see it, PHP sees `<?` part of your `<?xml` as a php open tag and generates an error.

Comment: I see that short_open_tag is ON, however... it's working for all of my websites except one... Do you know why it's having such behaviour?

Comment: @ChinLeung Do the other files that are working use an extension that is parseable by PHP? I mean can they run php code?

Comment: @KodosJohnson Yes, every websites hosted on the server are coded in PHP.

Comment: @ChinLeung Ok so those other files that are working fine do the same thing? They include a `sitemap.html` file?

Comment: Yes, it's a custom CMS that's used by all the projects.

Comment: `short_open_tag` messing up with `<?xml` open tags is, in fact, well-known problem. So, maybe your other projects have this option disabled somewhere in the code or .htaccess if you're using apache, or somewhere else?

Answer (score 4):

If you're going to have PHP process HTML pages and it's working on every other site, then you're (obviously) dealing with a difficult-to-troubleshoot configuration issue.

You can either continue searching for the `short_open_tags` setting buried somewhere on the server or you could simply echo the XML declaration using PHP.

```
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>' ?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
    <url>
        <loc><?php echo SITE_URL . '/'; ?></loc>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
        <priority>1.00</priority>
    </url>

    <?php foreach ($this->data->content as $content): ?>
        <url>
            <loc><?php echo SITE_URL . $content->permalink; ?></loc>
            <lastmod><?php echo date("Y-m-d", $content->publish_date); ?></lastmod>
            <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
            <priority><?php echo $content->sitemap_index; ?></priority>
        </url>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</urlset>
```

Here's an older page on the topic:
[PHP opening tags and XML declaration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265905/php-opening-tags-and-xml-declaration)

I prefer to give all PHP code files the .php extension so it's abundantly clear that they contain code and not incur the overhead of having PHP process every HTML file, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: Also, the solution you've proposed is what I've wrote in my question as an alternative fix. However, I'm not looking for how to fix it, I'm looking for the cause.

Comment: Please read your question again. Your first sentence begins "I have a file that is including a file named sitemap.html..." Everyone is telling you that this is a configuration issue regarding short open tags, but unfortunately we cannot access your web server to view the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, this is due to the [short_open_tag option](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)

> Tells PHP whether the short form (`<? ?>`) of PHP's open tag should be allowed. **If you want to use PHP in combination with XML, you can disable this option in order to use `<?xml ?>` inline**. Otherwise, you can print it with PHP, for example: `<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0"?>'; ?>`. Also, if disabled, you must use the long form of the PHP open tag (`<?php ?>`).

Comment: `PHP_INI_PERDIR` Entry can be set in php.ini, .htaccess, httpd.conf or .user.ini (since PHP 5.3).  So doesn't work with `ini_set()`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Hmm, coulda sworn it worked with `ini_set` too. Oh well

Comment: Do you have any idea why it would work my other websites and not one in specific?